# How to initialize a signed char to unsigned values like 0xFF in C++?

Tags: c++

There are some cases where a byte array is implemented in a library using a char type, which is a signed type for many compilers.

Is there a simple, readable and correct way to initialize a signed char with a hex value which is greater than 127 and not bigger than 255?

Currently I end up with the following, and I keep thinking that there must be something simpler:

```
const unsigned char ff_unsigned = 0xff;
const char ff_signed = static_cast<const char>(ff_unsigned);
```

I want a solution with no warnings, even when using higher compiler warning levels than the default.

The following solution e.g. creates C4310: cast truncates constant value with MSVC 2013:

```
const char ff_signed = char(0xff);
```

Comment: Would `ff_signed = '\xff'` work?

Comment: 7 bits of a signed 8-bit byte can NOT store a value larger than 127..edit: 0xff is clearly positive  number 255..but if you write as binary, it is not so clear: it could be 255 or -1 -- the bit pattern is most important -- you can *treat* that same data as signed or unsigned .

Comment: Writing signed byte = 255; is obviously not valid..but the bit pattern for 255 would be..its a little weird .

Comment: @ABuckau I fully agree that a signed value cannot be as big. My usecase is only interfering with libraries which use "signed char" when they only should use "unsigned char" because they are describing arrays of raw data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. Use single quotation characters with `\x` as the prefix. That denotes a hexadecimal literal `char` type.

For example: `'\xff'`.

But note that `char` can be signed or unsigned and up to and including C++11 it can even be a 1's complement signed type.

Answer (score 4):

```
const char ff_unsigned = '\xff';
```

Answer (score 0):

0xff is an int and '\xff' is a char.`You can use

```
const char ff_signed = (char)0xff;
```

or

```
const char ff_signed = '\xff';
```